# Windows 10: vertical scroll lines configuration per mouse

Tags: mouse, touchpad, scrolling

In "Mouse Properties -> Wheel -> Vertical scrolling" is it possible to configure number of lines that one mouse scroll will scroll, but this is global option.

I would like to have following config:

- Touchpad: 30 lines per scroll
- Mouse: 7 lines per scroll

Is there some way to configure vertical scroll lines per input device?