# Is there some way to change mouse scroll rows quickly from one value to another in Windows?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, scrolling, trackpoint

I have a laptop and there is a pointing stick (TrackPoint). It's convenient to use "mouse scroll rows" for 1 row and for mouse which comes from a dock station - 3 rows.

Is there some way switch it quickly? Maybe shell command...

P.S. And it'd be awesome to switch it automatically on connected device. :)
This request mentioned in [Windows 10: vertical scroll lines configuration per mouse](https://superuser.com/questions/1250878/windows-10-vertical-scroll-lines-configuration-per-mouse)
 question.

System: Windows 10.
Laptop: Thinkpad.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/download/) to set this option. [DllCall](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/DllCall.htm) can be used to invoke Winapi functions.

MSDN Reference: [SystemParametersInfoA function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa)

Note that not all apps react immediately to the change. Most will do, but some apps need to be restarted to feel the change (e.g. Notepad++).
Settings per device is not possible I think.

Example script to toggle between 1 and 5 rows (by pressing `F1` key):

```
setss(L) {
    dllcall("SystemParametersInfoA",   uint, 0x69,   uint,  L,   uintP, 0,   uint, 1 | 2)
}

toggle := 0
F1::
    toggle := !toggle
    if toggle
        ss := 1
    else 
        ss := 5
    setss(ss)
return
```

Comment: cool! I've wrote myself solution in Autohotkey already, actually, but yours some kinda more "system" one. So, if it works, I like it. Mikhail, could you explain what are the parameters meaning? Is there maybe AHK forum post?..

Comment: I just would like to learn how to change such kind of system parameters. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Kirby Added some info. So I look in MSDN, write down needed values and put in the Dllcall after the function name in same order and types as in function signature, see Dllcall docs on AHK site for examples (though some are not working). To find the fWinIni constants I used [Pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=spif&namespace=[All])  and of course google for Winapi & C++ examples, because you will find more than with other languages.

Comment: Well, sounds like a robust work. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: I tried  only the dllcall line ( changing the L to the desired value ).
It works.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to find anything that changes it individually for each device, since this is a desktop setting.

However, you could create a .reg-file with the following content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"WheelScrollLines"="3"
```

By running it, you change the scroll speed to three rows at a time. Change the value to '1', run it again, and well - you have a new scroll speed.

Easiest would probably be to create two files and bind them to any key combination or just put them somewhere accessible, like on Quick Start.

Good luck :-)

Comment: Thank you for this note. Well, it's something. But when I changed it directly, there is changes in behavior, unfortunately. :-|

Comment: typo: there is *no* changes in behavior.

Comment: Hmm, late reply I see. That is strange. I notice the same thing. I wonder if something needs a little restart for the change to take effect...